# Random parallelepipeds

Tags: python

Is there a way to generate random parallepepeds with dimensions x, y, z, based on the script exists in the link: [Generate random ellipsoids](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42217/generate-random-ellipsoids/42232#42232), which allows to generate random spheres. The purpose of my work is to make a study of a composite material which contains parallepeped reinforcements.

The problem of the script of generating spheres is that when parallelepede or cubes are used, the problem of overlapping between these particles will appear, since here we must check the condition between the two parallepeped bases which is different with the case of spheres.

The dimensions are displayed on the image such as the distance between the vertices of the two bases and the distance between the centers.
Thank you very much for your help.
[image]

Comment: The solids in your illustration are not just parallelepipeds, but also cuboids (their faces are orthogonal).. would that be true of the particles you're checking for intersection?

Comment: Yes, we also call cuboids,

Comment: I tried with the cube model, I changed some parameters as follows:                  # random scale 
min_scale = 0.018
max_scale = 0.018
depth = 0.08
# scale_factor .. scale down to help fit
scale_factor = 1
domain = 1
only_cubes = True

tries_per_cube = 256
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/24/2/1560276707-dsdsdsqd.png , How to adjust the dimensions of the cube and the distance between each two cubes, knowing that cubes are cuboids

Comment: No help until this day!!!!